# How to start an application when connecting an Xbox 360 controller

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, adapter, xbox360

This is my first post here and I was wondering, is it possible to have an application open when I connect an Xbox 360 controller to my Windows 10 laptop using the proprietary xbox 360 wireless receiver(driver v. 2.1.0.1349).

The application is an emulator that I use called psx2(v. 1.2.1) which is a playstation 2 emulator (can be found here http://pcsx2.net/download/releases/windows.html ). I thought it would be cool if when I connected the controller it would open automatically to save time.

My first reaction was to check autoplay settings for the controller but the device was not available there.

Is there a command that could accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You shouldn't need any additional software to use a XBox 360 controller on Windows 10 unless the application itself doesn't support a controller.

Comment: That was not the question, I was wondering if there is a way to link the controller so that when it connects to the system the psx2 application would open automatically, the controller connects to the computer without problem